# Change background image to video through css

Tags: css, html, html5-video

In the attached example ([here](http://compareyourtour.com/)) there is the first background image of the woman in the car, I would like to transfer this out and instead put an auto run, on loop video (mp4) full width and same height in the place. All other copy and content is to remain the same - any ideas how I can do this simply?

All other images if you click on the arrows should also remain. Thanks!

Comment: you have to use <video> element

Comment: Yes, but where do I call it from and where should the data sit?

Answer (score 0):

For simplicity. You may use a GIF as a `background-image:url(GIF_PATH)` instead of a video.

Here is a codepen example

https://codepen.io/leemark/pen/dJxHp

or else you have use the HTML  element to embed video content in a document.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video

Also you may also like to have a look at [owl corousel](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/demos/video.html)